# Controls on form private?

Tags: c#, .net, encapsulation, private-members

Can I access the control variables on a form?  Eg:

```
MyForm form = new MyForm();
form.button1.Visible = True;   // why doesn't this work?
```

Comment: Have you tried it?  This strikes me as a question that would take less time to test than it took to type into StackOverflow...

Comment: can't see a reason why this question is closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `public` or `internal` modifier of control via `Modifier` property windows or open designer.cs and set the access modifier.

Comment: Good to see someone has just answered the question instead of engaging in all this negativity.

Answer (score 2):

```
bool SearchAllChildren = true;
(this.Controls.Find("button1", SearchAllChildren )[0] as Button).Visible = true;
```

you can set `SearchAllChildren` to `false` so that it returns only controls on the form not nested controls (Controls in Other Controls)

Comment: Does this work even if the control is `private`?

Comment: Yes @CJ7 it does work on `private` controls too.